# setData on intent prevents sendBroadcast from working?

Tags: android

I have a BroadcastReceiver registered to listen for the following action..

```
public static final String MY_ACTION = "com.blah.intent.action.DOSOMETHING";
```

And in my code I have

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MY_ACTION);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

If I use this the broadcast is sent and received fine, however if I add a Uri using setData
before sending the broadcast by adding these lines..

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("/sdacrd/myfile");
intent.setData(uri);
```

If I setData the broadcast doesn't get received.

Can anyone explain why setting data on the intent prevents broadcasts from working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Android looks not only on ACTION, but also on type of the data and schema. You should tell that your receiver can receive this type by call to addDataSchema() or addDataType() on IntentFilter. If you want to just send String, why don't you use extras?

Comment: Yeah I was just using a string to start with but as the String I am sending is a Uri it just seemed to make sense to use setData

Comment: I'm not sure, but if you use it as data, then you have to specify type of that data like in MIME. So, It's more simple to use extras.

Comment: Yes setting the data type fixed this.

Comment: just note: it's possible to pass URI as extra, and then retrieve it using getParcelableExtra, because `android.net.Uri` implements `Parcelable`

Answer (score 1):

I agree with damluar.

From Android developer:
Add a new Intent data scheme to match against. If any schemes are included in the filter, then an Intent's data must be either one of these schemes or a matching data type. If no schemes are included, then an Intent will match only if it includes no data.

Vice verse, if you add data in Intent, you must add data type or scheme in the intent filter.